# including html image tag inside php in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

```
<?php foreach($fullmap as $tr)
    {
    $map->addMarkerByAddress($tr->latitude.','.$tr->longitude, " ", '<h3>'.$tr->restaurant_name.'</h3><img width="80" height="80" src="'.base_url().$tr->images.'" class="img-circle" alt="user1" style="width:50px; height:50px;"><p>'.$tr->description.'<a href="'.site_url('main/restros_quick_view').'?restro_id='.$tr->restaurant_id.'" class="three-inner-detail">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="color: red;">Detail</span></a></p>', "http://demos.thesoftwareguy.in/google-map1/icons/islam.png" );
    } ?>
```

Hello friends the above code is working fine,but as u see in the last line am showing icon from the link,but i need to show my own icon,so how can i write img src tag inside php.my icon is in image folder,and name of icon is test1.jpg,,am using codeigniter frame work

Comment: Have you tried like this "/path/to/image/test1.jpg"

Comment: yeah i tried,but its not showing anything

Comment: '<img src="'.base_url().'"/images/islam2.png/>' i tried this instead of "http://demos.thesoftwareguy.in/google-map1/icons/islam.png" but its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to put the IMG tag the Google marker just want the ***Image Path*** so just provide the path and img tag will be added by map only.

```
<?php foreach($fullmap as $tr)
{
$map->addMarkerByAddress($tr->latitude.','.$tr->longitude, " ", '<h3>'.$tr->restaurant_name.'</h3><img width="80" height="80" src="'.base_url().$tr->images.'" class="img-circle" alt="user1" style="width:50px; height:50px;"><p>'.$tr->description.'<a href="'.site_url('main/restros_quick_view').'?restro_id='.$tr->restaurant_id.'" class="three-inner-detail">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="color: red;">Detail</span></a></p>', base_url() . "assets/images/icon.png" );
} ?>
```

you can write this `base_url() . "assets/images/icon.png"`

Comment: how can i write,can you please do it,by using my above code